# How to access self.context property using a variable in flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to access a property exist in the `self.context` using a `variable`. I have a variable name `"prop"` and it contains a value and it is already set in the self.context. I am using `Flask Restplus` framework.

```
prop = 'binding'
```

If I try to access this property like below then it gives me an error:

```
Object is not subscriptable
```

I want to know if there is any way to get the value? Like doing this:

```
print(self.context[prop])
```

I only get one solution don't know if its correct or not, I tried this :

```
self.context.__getattribute__(prop)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, the simplest is using `getattr`:

```
getattr(self.context, prop)
```

This function internally calls `__getattribute__` so it's the same as your code, just a little neater.

However, you still have the problem that you probably only want to access some of the context, while not risking editing values set by different parts of your application. A much better way would be to store a dict in context:

```
self.context.attributes = {}
self.context.attributes["binding"] = False
print(self.context.attributes[prop])
```

This way, only certain context variables can be accessed and those that are meant to be dynamic don't mess with any used by your application code directly.